# Does PO3- exist as a free ion or in a cyclic/linear polymeric form?

Tags: homework, ions, molecular-structure, structural-formula

My book says that $\ce{PO3-}$ exists as cyclic or linear polymeric structure but doesn't elaborate on this. I Googled this and found no result either.

Also, what would be the structure of $\ce{PO3-}$ cyclic or linear polymeric structure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hexametaphosphate for example

Comment: Also, there is nothing unusual about that: $\ce{SiO3^2-}$, too, exists as a variety of polymeric structures, but never as a free ion.